# Yii zii.widgets.grid.CGridView custom field

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, zii-widgets

I am new to yii. In my blocked-recruiter view's admin.php page i have a CGridView widget. the candidate_id is the foreign key of candidate table. So now in blocked recruiter view the candidate_id is coming by default. But i want to show the candidate name here, which is in the candidate table. to get the candidate name by candidate_id i have to use `Candidate::model()->findByAttributes('id'=>$candidate_id)->name;` But i am not able to use the code, basically i dont khow how do i use it.

Code in admin.php of blocked-recruiter view page.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'blocked-recruiter-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'candidate_id',
        'recruiter_id',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

So, please help to to get the `candidate_name` here instate of `candidate_id`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blocked-recruiter Model, `BlockedRecruiter` i presume, define a relation `candidate` like this:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'candidate'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Candidate', 'candidate_id'),
    );
}
```

The you can access the candidate's name in your `GridView` using `candidate.name` instead of `candidate_id`